# How to stop inline-block elements in IE (Internet Explorer) gaining focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, focus

I have a focusable outer container (using `tabindex="1"`), which contains a series of spans. All of these spans have the rule `display:inline-block`. I noticed that some css rules, which use the focus selector for highlighting, weren't working in IE.

Apparently this is because my outer container wasn't actually focused. Instead the inner spans (which don't have a tabindex and shouldn't be focusable) are taking the focus.

I've replicated the problem in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JoolsCaesar/e68176tk/). I have a focusable div containing 4 spans with different `display` rules (`initial`, `inline`, `block`, `inline-block`). On `mouseup` I call `focus()` on the element you clicked. The outer div gains focus in all but the case of the `inline-block` span.

HTML:

```
<body id="body">
<div tabindex="1" id="outerDiv">
Outer div
<span id="inlineSpan">Inline span.</span>
<span id="inlineBlockSpan">Inline-block span.</span>
<span id="blockSpan">Block span.</span>
<span id="initialSpan">Initial span.</span>
</div>
<div id="output">
</div>
</body>
```

Javascript (using jquery):

```
$("span").on("mouseup",function(){
    $(this).focus();
  setTimeout(function(){
        $("#output").append(document.activeElement.id+"<br>")
   });
})
```

CSS:

```
#inlineSpan{
  display:inline;
}
#inlineBlockSpan{
  display:inline-block;
}
#blockSpan{
  display:block;
}
#initialSpan{
  display:initial;
}

span,#outerDiv{
  border: 1px black solid;
  padding:1px
}
```

Is this a bug with IE? I haven't seen it in other browsers. Is there a way to stop it?

Unfortunately the two things contributing to this are in third party code. jQuery-UI is calling `focus()` on `mouseup`:

```
_mouseUp: function( event ) {
   this._unblockFrames();

   //If the ddmanager is used for droppables, inform the manager that dragging has stopped (see #5003)
   if ( $.ui.ddmanager ) {
      $.ui.ddmanager.dragStop(this, event);
   }

   // Only need to focus if the event occurred on the draggable itself, see #10527
   if ( this.handleElement.is( event.target ) ) {
      // The interaction is over; whether or not the click resulted in a drag, focus the element
      this.element.focus();
   }

   return $.ui.mouse.prototype._mouseUp.call(this, event);
},
```

and jstree is structuring the spans using `inline-block`, so ideally any fix would leave the third-party code unchanged.

**Edit:** Starting to think this is just an IE11 bug. It occurs without any programmatic focus and can be seen in [this amended js](https://jsfiddle.net/JoolsCaesar/e68176tk/21/). I've raised [a bug for microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/2499233/ie11-elements-with-display-inline-block-which-are-children-of-focusable-elements-can-be-given-focus-even-if-they-are-not-themselves-focusable), but I can't imagine them doing anything about it now they're focused on Edge.

**Edit 2:** Microsoft aren't going to fix it or rather they are of the position that it is fixed by you not using IE11:

> Thank you for the feedback. This issue appears to have been fixed in
>   Microsoft Edge. We're not presently working on feature bugs in
>   Internet Explorer outside of security-related issues.

Comment: Hi, what is your goal ? because in your sample, there is a workaround by replacing `$("span").mouseup()` by `$('#outerDiv').click(function() { $(this).focus();});`

Comment: @Yoplaboom My goal is to stop the spans gaining focus, when focus() is called on them i.e. the way it behaves in every browser apart from internet explorer. As I said, unfortunately, the call to focus() is occurring in jquery UIs code because these spans are also draggables.

Comment: I've added the culprit code from jquery UI to my question

Answer (score 1):

So far all I can think of 3 solutions.

1. Patch jstree to create nodes with a different structure e.g. a block span within an in-line span.
2. Patch jquery UI to only call `focus()` on focusable elements (looking at parent elements too.

   Something like replacing `this.element.focus();` with:

   ```
   this.element.closest(":focusable").focus();
   ```
3. Move the focus on focus ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JoolsCaesar/e68176tk/23/)):

   ```
   $outerDiv.on("focus",".inline-block-span-class", function(){
       $outerDiv.focus();
   });
   ```
4. <s>Wait for Microsoft to fix it.</s>

I'm leaning towards number 3.

---

Microsoft aren't going to fix it:

> Thank you for the feedback. This issue appears to have been fixed in
> Microsoft Edge. We're not presently working on feature bugs in
> Internet Explorer outside of security-related issues.